# WKWebView crashes on deinit

Tags: swift, crash, wkwebview

I have this hierarchy - UIViewController -> ChildUIViewController -> WKWebView.

I had an issue with the WKWebView message handler that leaked and prevented the child view controller from being released.

After some reading I found a way to fix the retain cycle by using this fix - [WKWebView causes my view controller to leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26383031/wkwebview-causes-my-view-controller-to-leak)

Now I can see  that the child view controller is reaching `deinit` but right after that the WKWebView is crashing on `deinit` (No useful log from Xcode).

Any Idea or direction what could be the issue ?

Thanks

**UPDATE**
here is my code - [Code Gist](https://gist.github.com/prep4gmat/eac0a7ce2ef006ed339d9966c14e5828)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Put this inside deinit method of **child view controller**:

```
webView.scrollView.delegate = nil
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks!
We banged our head on this one, can you explain how did find out ?

Comment: @shannoga looks like `WKWebView` stores `__unsafe_unretained` pointer to your delegate. Sometimes on web view deallocated not immediate after view controller deallocation and this cause crash when web view tries to notify delegate something.

Answer (score 9):

Don't forget to remove WKWebView's delegates you added:

```
deinit {
    webView.navigationDelegate = nil
    webView.scrollView.delegate = nil
}
```

Looks like WKWebView stores __unsafe_unretained pointer to your delegate. Sometimes when web view deallocated not immediate after view controller deallocation. This cause crash when web view tries to notify delegate something.

Answer (score 3):

I tried with same way as you mentioned. It works perfectly for me. Code which i tried is,

```
class CustomWKWebView : WKWebView {

    deinit {
        print("CustomWKWebView - dealloc")
    }

}


class LeakAvoider : NSObject, WKScriptMessageHandler {
    weak var delegate : WKScriptMessageHandler?
    init(delegate:WKScriptMessageHandler) {
        self.delegate = delegate
        super.init()
    }
    func userContentController(userContentController: WKUserContentController,
        didReceiveScriptMessage message: WKScriptMessage) {
            self.delegate?.userContentController(
                userContentController, didReceiveScriptMessage: message)
    }

    deinit {
        print("LeakAvoider - dealloc")
    }

}

class ChildViewController: UIViewController , WKScriptMessageHandler{

    var webView = CustomWKWebView()

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(webView)
        webView.frame = self.view.bounds;
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        let url = NSURL(string: "https://appleid.apple.com")
        webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL:url!))
        webView.configuration.userContentController.addScriptMessageHandler(
            LeakAvoider(delegate: self), name: "dummy")
    }

    func userContentController(userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceiveScriptMessage message: WKScriptMessage)
    {

    }

    deinit {
        print("ChaildViewController- dealloc")
        webView.stopLoading()
        webView.configuration.userContentController.removeScriptMessageHandlerForName("dummy")
    }
}


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    deinit {
        print("ViewController - dealloc")
    }
}
```

Log after popping ViewController is:

```
ViewController - dealloc
ChaildViewController- dealloc
LeakAvoider - dealloc
CustomWKWebView - dealloc
```

**UPDATE**

Put below lines in your WebViewViewController's viewWillDisappear function.

```
    webView.navigationDelegate = nil
    webView.scrollView.delegate = nil
```

I tried by setting these two delegates in my code and it started crashing. Solved by putting above lines in viewWillDisappear of ChildViewController.

Comment: Thanks for the work you've done. I will check for other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, the reason might caused by weak reference to it.
I'm sure that you have instantiated local variable of wrapped class with WKWebView.