# Swift - setURLSchemeHandler causes a memory leak (WKWebview)

Tags: swift

I am using setURLSchemeHandler (with the WKURLSchemeHandler protocol) as follows:

```
let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
config.setURLSchemeHandler(self, forURLScheme: "local")
WebView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:self.view.frame.width, height:self.view.frame.height), configuration: config)
```

When I dismiss this viewcontroller, "deinit" is not called.
Reason for this is using "self" in:

```
config.setURLSchemeHandler(self, forURLScheme: "local")
```

My question is, how to remove the scheme handler before dismissing the view?

Comment: Did you try to call the same set, but with nil? e.g. `config.setURLSchemeHandler(nil, forURLScheme: "local")`

Comment: Maybe you can try some workaround like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26383031/wkwebview-causes-my-view-controller-to-leak

Comment: @ytrewq Yes, I did try to unset it that way, but this raises an error saying that there is already a registered URL scheme handler.

Answer (score 2):

Based on an answer to a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26383032/12078019) (thanks to @DefyingL for the tip), I now made the following solution:

```
class LeakAvoider : NSObject, WKURLSchemeHandler {
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, start urlSchemeTask: WKURLSchemeTask) {
        self.delegate?.webView(webView, start: urlSchemeTask)
    }
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, stop urlSchemeTask: WKURLSchemeTask) {
        self.delegate?.webView(webView, stop: urlSchemeTask)
    }
    
    weak var delegate : WKURLSchemeHandler?
    init (delegate:WKURLSchemeHandler) {
        self.delegate = delegate
        super.init()
    }
    
}
```

And then set the scheme handler as follows:

```
config.setURLSchemeHandler(LeakAvoider(delegate:self), forURLScheme: "local")
```

Comment: You saved my day! Thanks. The WKURLSchemeHandler wrapper works fine.